# Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with selenium

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, automation

I am facing error of `Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`.also I have found after some search `Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &`. but unable to configure this through jenkins admin page.

can anyone help me out for this.

Comment: after adding `Xvfb plugin` while updating changes.I am getting  `net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["scm"] is not a JSONObject.
` this error.

Answer (score 0):

Now chrome comes with a headless mode. So, we don't need xvfb. We just need to an argument in capabilities.

```
chromeOptions: {
       args: ['--headless','--disable-gpu']
}
```